# What does =~ mean in VimScript?

Tags: operators, vim

I can't for the life of me find an answer to this either on google or here or in the help files.

```
if "test.c" =~ "\.c"
```

At first I thought `=~` mean ends in, but observe these results:

```
Command                               Result
echo "test.c" =~ "\.c"                1
echo "test.c" =~ "\.pc"               0
echo "test.pc" =~ "\.c"               1
echo "testc" =~ "\.c"                 1
echo "ctest" =~ "\.c"                 1
echo "ctestp" =~ "\.pc"               0
echo "pctestp" =~ "\.pc"              0
echo ".pctestp" =~ "\.pc"             0
```

An explanation would be great. A link to a site attempting to decipher VimScript would be even better.

Comment: There is no way `"ctest =~ "\.c"` and `".pctestp" !~ "\.pc"`.

Comment: By the way, it's probably best to avoid `=~`, but use `=~#` or `=~?` instead, which explicitly specify whether you wish case-sensitivity or insensitivity. With a plain `=~`, it depends on the user's current settings. More info: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr4

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[From Vim's online help (`:h =~`)](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-%3D%7E):

> Compare two [...] expressions [...]

```
regexp matches         =~
regexp doesn't match   !~
```

> The "=~" and "!~" operators match the lefthand argument with the righthand argument, which is used as a pattern.  See [pattern](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#pattern) for what a pattern is. [...]

Example:

```
    :if str =~ " "
    :  echo "str contains a space"
    :endif
    :if str !~ '\.$'
    :  echo "str does not end in a full stop"
    :endif
```

You might try your test cases again.  I get, for example, inconsistent with yours:

```
echo ".pctestp" =~ "\.pc"             1
```

And double-quotes vs single quotes seem to affect how the backslash is interpreted:

```
echo "test.pc" =~ "\.c"               1
echo "test.pc" =~ '\.c'               0
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the double quotes that were giving me the strange behavior

Comment: @puk What I've not yet located are the docs that explain the differences in quoting...

Comment: I find the documentation on vim is all over the place. The `:help` pages are exceedingly helpful for simple things like `d` or `:ls`, but useless if you don't know what you're looking for (ie. `stridx()`). Similarly, the vim wiki is great for keys and commands, but not so much for functions like the aforementioned `stridx()`.

Comment: Your note on double- vs. single-quotes solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html

  For strings there are two more items:

  ```
  a =~ b      matches with
  a !~ b      does not match with
  ```

  The left item "a" is used as a string.  The right item "b" is used as a
  pattern, like what's used for searching.  Example:

  ```
  :if str =~ " "
  :  echo "str contains a space"
  :endif
  :if str !~ '\.$'
  :  echo "str does not end in a full stop"
  :endif
  ```